# Is it possible to get "Low Disk Space" notification from windows in win32 or MFC application?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc

I have a MFC application which is actually show files of connected USB devices. [Multi-filter Drag and Drop](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/840/How-to-Implement-Drag-and-Drop-Between-Your-Progra) is enabled for this application and works perfectly except **“Low Level Disk”** warning from Windows. It can drag files from **PC to MFC Application** and **MFC Application to PC**. When **“Low Level Disk Space”** warning is showing from PC, Drag and Drop is not working and Application get crushed even enough memory is available to paste/drop the files. I have checked that there is enough memory is available before dropping the dragged files.

After googling I have found [this link](https://www.howtogeek.com/324956/how-much-free-space-should-you-leave-on-your-windows-pc/) that states,

> Windows is not allowing to copy/paste due to “Low Level Disk Space” warning even you have enough space to copy/paste the files.

So I have to consider **“Low Level Disk Space”** memory size also beside my dragged file size. But I didn’t find any answer about the below questions:

1. What is the Minimum level amount of memory need to avoid “LowLeveDiskSpace” warning?
2. Is there any way to get this “LowLeveDiskSpace” notification through MFC or Win32 application?

Comment: For point one: its difficult use google?

Comment: @user2120666 I didn't find any proper answer for the Question number 1. That's why i'm asking here to get expert opinion.

Comment: What about 2nd answer on https://superuser.com/questions/234332/what-is-the-drive-level-low-space-warning-threshold-for-windows-7

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is documented.

The shell calls `StringCchPrintfW` on a `L"LowDiskOn%C"` format string where the %C parameter is a upper-case drive letter. It uses that string to wait on a named mutex. I'm not sure if the shell itself periodically checks the free space or if the mutex is signaled by something else.

The implementation has probably changed over the years.